# How to disable a css rule for a wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress theme, and a plugin.

The plugin uses the theme stylesheet, which is fine except there is one rule I would like to disable *for the plugin pages only*:

```
.sidebar-content-sidebar #inner {
background: url(images/inner-scs.png);
}
```

I would like the above rule to be disabled, because the background images do not apply for those pages.

How can I do that?

Comment: Depends what you mean by plugin pages, I guess. Could you, for example, hook into [body_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) on your plugin pages to add a custom body class only on those pages? If so, then you could override with `.your-class .sidebar-content-sidebar #inner { background: none; }`, say. Being more specific, it would override the theme's style.

Comment: @Matt Gibson The plugin actually has a dashboard with a field to add custom css; adding the snippet from Vipul below worked for me. I am not sure how the custom css for the plugin actually works.

Comment: Ah, I see, I assumed the plugin was your own development, rather than just one you were using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css  :

```
.sidebar-content-sidebar #inner 
{
   background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the :not pseudo-selector to exclude pages with a specific class or ID applied to the **body** tag (e.g. '#plugin-bg-disabled')

```
body:not(#plugin-bg-disabled) .sidebar-content-sidebar #inner {
  background: url(images/inner-scs.png);
}
```